# Exclude some characters in Unicode category

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying to implement a rule along the lines of "all characters in the Letter and Symbol Unicode categories *except* a few reserved characters." From the [lexer rules](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexer-rule-elements), I know I can use `\p{___}` to match against Unicode categories, but I am unsure of how to handle excluding certain characters.

Looking at example grammars, I am led a few different directions. For example, the [Java 9 grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java9/Java9.g4#L1826) seems to use predicates in order to directly use Java's built in `isJavaIdentifier()` while [others](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/kotlin/UnicodeClasses.g4) manually define every valid character.

How can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without target specific code, you will have to define the ranges yourself so that the chars you want to exclude are not part of these ranges. You cannot use `\p{...}` and then exclude certain characters from it.

With target specific code, you can do as in the Java 9 grammar:

```
@lexer::members {
  boolean aCustomMethod(int character) {
    // Your logic to see if 'character' is valid. You're sure
    // that it's at least a char from \p{Letter} or \p{Symbol}
    return true;
  }
}

TOKEN
 : [\p{Letter}\p{Symbol}] {aCustomMethod(_input.LA(-1))}?
 ;
```